# Why does APNS deliver only last queued notification instead of all queued notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

**Problem Statement** : I'm using voip notification to show local notification.I'm trying to send notification from Apns to a offline device. So, It queued all pending notifications. But, It only send last queued notification once device becomes
online.

Answer (score 2):

As per apple documentation [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1)

**Quality of Service, Store-and-Forward, and Coalesced Notifications**

> Apple Push Notification service includes a Quality of Service (QoS)
>   component that performs a store-and-forward function. If APNs attempts
>   to deliver a notification and the destination device is offline, APNs
>   stores the notification for a limited period of time and delivers it
>   when the device becomes available again. This component stores only
>   the most recent notification per device and per app. If a device is
>   offline, sending a notification request targeting that device causes
>   the previous request to be discarded. If a device remains offline for
>   a long time, all its stored notifications in APNs are discarded.
>
> To allow the coalescing of similar notifications, you can include a
>   collapse identifier within a notification request. Normally, when a
>   device is online, each notification request that you send to APNs
>   results in a notification delivered to the device. However, when the
>   apns-collapse-id key is present in your HTTP/2 request header, APNs
>   coalesces requests whose value for that key is the same. For example,
>   a news service that sends the same headline twice could use the same
>   collapse identifier value for both requests. APNs would then coalesce
>   the two requests into a single notification for delivery to the
>   device.

Comment: thanx for the answer but this is not what I'm expecting.

Comment: @ShivamSharma you shouldn't rely on APNS.

Comment: @J.Doe then on what should I use? any reliable source to send notifications?